# hide fragments in frame layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, show-hide, android-framelayout

I'm using a frame layout to have more than one fragment in the same section of the screen.

So, I have a frame layout tag and then few fragment tags under it in XML.
So, I can see the overlap of these fragments.

I want to hide all the fragments except the one I want to show. 
Where should I call the hide function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support library for fragments use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(<resource id for frame layout>, <new fragment>).commit()`

This would replace all the fragments that are attached to this framelayout with the new fragment.

Comment: Can't I do it without using the support lib?

Comment: yes you can simple use getFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: @Namratha Yes you can as suggested by Atrix1987 here. But you should use it if you want to support versions of android prior to Honey comb which don't have Fragments api.

Comment: Why are you using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`? Do you expect that state loss might occur here?